# How can I best combine different objects in a way that reduces vertices and edges?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices, edges

New to Blender. Let's say I have a cylinder and rectangular prism that intersect each other along their long sides, like so:

[image]

I want to merge these shapes in a way that eliminates the intersecting edges but preserves their external geometry, something like this:

[image]

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Boolean* modifier should work perfectly for this purpose.

- First, split the separate parts into individual objects (<kbd>P</kbd> with everything selected in edit mode).
- Then, add the *Boolean* modifier to either of the objects, set it to *Union,* and select the other object. You can further edit the mesh by applying the modifier (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>).

After applying the modifier, you will be left with two objects: the joined mesh and the target object of the modifier.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed!